# Is there a utility to create blank images?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm looking for an xpm icon to use as a placeholder until I make something better.

Are there any linux command line tools that create blank images of specified dimensions? Like people use `touch` to create blank text files.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `convert` command from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) can be used:

To create a 32x32 image with a white background:

```
convert -size 32x32 xc:white empty.jpg
```

To create a 32x32 image with a transparent background:

```
convert -size 32x32 xc:transparent empty2.png
```

Comment: To specify the DPI setting, use the -density 96 switch. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#density

Comment: Please note that jpg's can't be transparent.  So, this command will work, but with an ext other than jpg

Comment: @colemik the `-density` setting will have no effect when creating blank images

Comment: Use `PNG32:empty.png` to get a 32 bit png instead of a 1 bit greyscale png.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `convert -size 123x456 xc:white x.png`.  `convert` is part of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have ImageMagick installed, you can use a short Perl script:

```
use GD::Simple;
my $i = GD::Simple->new(32,32);
open my $out, '>', 'empty.png' or die;
binmode $out;
print $out $i->png;
```

Using Python:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (32,32), color='white')
img.save('empty.png')
quit()
```